# Import modules from HTTPS in a Service Worker

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I'm attempting to implement Firebase Cloud Messaging for the web using their v9 SDK, which is heavily pushing using Javascript modules... and I need to register the service worker inside of a Vue component.

The service worker keeps screaming "you cannot use import statements outside of a module".  So, I tried adding the `{type: 'module'}` option to the `navigator.serviceWorker.register` call... but no luck.  I also tried the old-school `importScripts` to no avail.  The small number of examples online show `<script type='module'>` but that makes no sense inside of a Vue component, at least from what I understand.

Here's the entirety of the service worker:

```
import { fbConfig } from "/js/firebase/firebase-config.js";
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-app.js"
import { getMessaging, onBackgroundMessage } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-messaging-sw.js"

// Create the instance of Firebase & Messaging
const fbApp = initializeApp(fbConfig)
const messaging = getMessaging(fbApp);

onBackgroundMessage(messaging, (payload) => {
    console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);

    const notificationTitle = payload.message.notification.title;
    const notificationOptions = payload.message.notification.body;

    let outcome = self.registration.showNotification(
        notificationTitle,
        notificationOptions
    );
    console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] showNotification outcome', outcome)
});
```

Here's where I'm attempting to register it, which is inside of the "mounted()" section of my Vue component:

```
        if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
            navigator.serviceWorker.register(
                '/firebase-messaging-sw.js', {
                    type: 'module'
                })
                .then(reg => {
                    console.log(`Service Worker Registration (Scope: ${reg.scope})`);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    const msg = `Service Worker Error (${error})`;
                    console.error(msg);
                });
        } else {
            // happens when the app isn't served over HTTPS or if the browser doesn't support service workers
            console.warn('Service Worker not available');
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it with this code for the SW:

```js
importScripts('/__/firebase/9.0.1/firebase-app-compat.js');
importScripts('/__/firebase/9.0.1/firebase-messaging-compat.js');
importScripts('/__/firebase/init.js');

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function(payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  // Customize notification here
  const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: 'Background Message body.',
    icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
  };

  self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
    notificationOptions);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but Firebase disagrees.  I moved the whole onBackgroundMessage method call into my Vue component, along with its import, and got the following error message:
`vue.esm.js?a026:628 [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "FirebaseError: Messaging: This method is available in a service worker context. (messaging/only-available-in-sw)."`

Comment: Can you pls try it the the new code in the answer. It uses the `compat` version of the new SDK but would like to see if it works properly. It won't work in debug mode because the import need to come from firebase hosting.

Comment: Done... but it seems I'm in a catch-22.  The prior error was that import statements weren't allowed outside of modules.  The new error is that importScripts is not supported in modules.  I'm so completely confused.

Full error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': Module scripts don't support importScripts().`

I'm honestly starting to think that the folks at Google/Firebase somehow missed this particular use-case... (NPM usable for the Vue front-end, unable to bundle the service worker needed for messaging when the browser is in the background.)